# How to fix nginx 502 bad gateway error?

Tags: nginx

I have set up a nginx server several weeks ago, at that time `http://180.76.117.109/1/#/home` worked well.

However, when I recheck that today in a browser, it returns an `502 bad gateway` error.

Here is the result of `sudo tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2018/03/26 10:13:12 [error] 9456#9456: *2580202 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 180.97.106.39, server: _, request: "GET /?season=1&league_id=1'%20AND%20(SELECT%20*%20FROM%20(SELECT(SLEEP(5)))oUvL)%20AND%20'kSYX'='kSYX&match_day=1&team_id=1 HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/?season=1&league_id=1'%20AND%20(SELECT%20*%20FROM%20(SELECT(SLEEP(5)))oUvL)%20AND%20'kSYX'='kSYX&match_day=1&team_id=1", host: "180.76.117.109:80"
2018/03/26 10:13:12 [error] 9456#9456: *2580204 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 180.97.106.39, server: _, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=duplicator_package_delete HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=duplicator_package_delete", host: "180.76.117.109:80"
2018/03/26 10:13:12 [error] 9456#9456: *2580206 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 180.97.106.39, server: _, request: "GET /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_bulk-editor&type=title&orderby=post_date&order=asc HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_bulk-editor&type=title&orderby=post_date&order=asc", host: "180.76.117.109:80"
2018/03/26 10:13:12 [error] 9456#9456: *2580208 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 180.97.106.163, server: _, request: "GET /?action=data_management&cpmvc_do_action=mvparse&f=datafeed&method=remove&rruleType=del_only&calendarId=1%20AND%20(SELECT%20*%20FROM%20(SELECT(SLEEP(5)))nDnr) HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/?action=data_management&cpmvc_do_action=mvparse&f=datafeed&method=remove&rruleType=del_only&calendarId=1%20AND%20(SELECT%20*%20FROM%20(SELECT(SLEEP(5)))nDnr)", host: "180.76.117.109:80"
2018/03/26 10:13:12 [error] 9456#9456: *2580210 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 180.97.106.39, server: _, request: "GET /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", host: "180.76.117.109:80"
2018/03/26 10:13:12 [error] 9456#9456: *2580212 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 180.97.106.39, server: _, request: "GET /wp-admin/admin.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/wp-admin/admin.php", host: "180.76.117.109:80"
2018/03/26 10:13:12 [error] 9456#9456: *2580214 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 180.97.106.39, server: _, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=duplicator_package_delete HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=duplicator_package_delete", host: "180.76.117.109:80"
2018/03/26 10:13:12 [error] 9456#9456: *2580216 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 180.97.106.39, server: _, request: "GET /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_bulk-editor&type=title&orderby=post_date%2c(select%20*%20from%20(select(sleep(5)))a)&order=asc HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_bulk-editor&type=title&orderby=post_date%2c(select%20*%20from%20(select(sleep(5)))a)&order=asc", host: "180.76.117.109:80"
2018/03/26 10:48:39 [error] 9456#9456: *2580218 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 10:48:39 [error] 9456#9456: *2580218 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 10:48:51 [error] 9456#9456: *2580218 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 10:48:51 [error] 9456#9456: *2580218 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 10:51:22 [error] 9456#9456: *2580223 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 10:51:22 [error] 9456#9456: *2580223 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 11:07:58 [error] 9456#9456: *2580226 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 11:07:58 [error] 9456#9456: *2580226 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 11:07:59 [error] 9456#9456: *2580226 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 11:07:59 [error] 9456#9456: *2580226 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 11:07:59 [error] 9456#9456: *2580226 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 11:07:59 [error] 9456#9456: *2580226 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 11:08:18 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 11:08:18 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 11:08:19 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 11:08:19 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 11:08:20 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 11:08:20 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 11:08:30 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 11:08:30 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
2018/03/26 11:08:31 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/", host: "180.76.117.109"
2018/03/26 11:08:32 [error] 5593#5593: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.169.4.93, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "180.76.117.109", referrer: "http://180.76.117.109/1/"
```

Does anyone know what may be the problem?

Comment: I stopped `pm2` by `sudo pm2 stop 0`, then restarted the application by `sudo service mongod start` and `sudo npm start`, then it worked. Now I can also use `sudo pm2 start npm -- start` to start the application... Very wired...

Answer (score 1):

Check the upstream server, i.e. "http://180.76.117.109:3000/". It is very likely down.

Comment: Indeed, `http://180.76.117.109:3000/` does not work in a browser. But I am not sure it worked before, my mean-stack application was supposed to be launched by `http://180.76.117.109/1/#/home`.

Comment: When `http://180.76.117.109/1/#/home` works well, `http://180.76.117.109:3000/1/#/home` should works, too. Nginx is just a proxy here, which proxies the request of 180.76.117.109:80, to 180.76.117.109:3000. Maybe you cannot access 180.76.117.109:3000 from other machines because of firewall, but you can absolutely accesses from 180.76.117.109 itself, or to say `http://127.0.0.1:3000/1/#/home` the same thing (when everything is OK).